# Shell script in Gradle build: java.io.IOException

Tags: android, shell, gradle, build.gradle

I have the following lines in my build.gradle file of my Android project:

```
"./prebuild.sh".execute()
```

But during the build I get this error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "./prebuild.sh": error=2, No such file or directory
```

The prebuild.sh script is in the root directory of the app and executable.
What's weird is that this exact build works for everyone on the team, just not on my machine (M1). I also remember that this used to work months ago.

This happens on a fresh clone of the repository and a fresh install of Android Studio.

I think I've narrowed it down to a problem with the working directory. If I try to print it like this:

```
println new File(".").absolutePath
```

I get the following:

```
/Users/ale/.gradle/daemon/6.5/.
```

Which is obviously not my project directory.

Any hints on what I could do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a functional shell prompt; pass the absolute path instead of `.` current working directory:

```
if(rootProject.file('prebuild.sh').exists()) {
    commandLine 'sh', rootProject.file('prebuild.sh').absolutePath
} else {
    println "missing: prebuild.sh"
}
```

---

Or how you start it as process, one can also pass the current working directory as second argument:

```
def proc = "./prebuild.sh".execute([], rootProject.absolutePath)
proc.waitForProcessOutput(System.out, System.err)
```

I'd run `cd` first, then `pwd` should return the expected value:

```
def proc = "cd ${rootProject.absolutePath} && pwd".execute()
...
```

Comment: I added a check to see if the file exists like you mentioned: if(rootProject.file('prebuild.sh').exists()) and it does! No idea why it's throwing an error though

Comment: It's the home/working directory of the Gradle daemon. Either issue `cd` first or use absolute path; it also matters if the code is within a task or loose... https://linux.die.net/man/1/pwd

Answer (score 0):

Check if the file has DOS line endings (\r\n). This can lead to a confusing "no such file or directory", because it searches for a file called `/bin/sh\r` (ending with an actual carriage return), which does not exist.

Comment: How would it read the file, when it cannot find it (as `error=2` suggests)?

Comment: Shouldn't this be on every machine then? As I mentioned, this script works for other devs.

Comment: In the other machines the file might have been checked out with unix line endings, git can convert line endings during check in/out depending on its configuration. Also, are the other machines also macs? If they're not, other systems (such as cygwin) might be more tolerant.